# Activate all Site Collection features as an existing site with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am creating new site collections with PowerShell and would like them to have all required Site Collection Features active once they have been created.

I would prefer to point a PowerShell script at an existing site collection, detect which Site Collection Features are already active in that site, and then activate them all in the new sites.

If anyone has a PowerShell script handy I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach:

1. Create a new empty site collection
2. Activate all features needed
3. Create a template out of this site (see Site Settings)
4. When creating a new site collection use your custom site template

This could be an alternative solution for your question. **If this helps, please give feedback.**

Comment: Agree that is a good suggestion and I would do that normally.  In this instance I am importing exported sub sites (using Import-SPWeb) into new empty site collections and I'm finding that not all site collection features required for the exported sub site are being activated after import.

Comment: Ok, I never ran into that problem site features being not activated as expected. Then you only have the chance to do this by Enable-SPFeature. Maybe this post gives you all needed information: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74165/activating-site-collection-level-feature-with-powershell-script

Comment: I can use Get-SPFeature -Site … on the master site collection or template, then pipe the results to Enable-SPFeature on the new site collection to ensure all required features are active.